# Pytorch forward return tensor versus scalar

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

Let's say I have a Pytorch model with the following forward function:

```
def forward(self, input_tensors):
    """
    dimension of all variables:
    - input_tensors: (heads, batch, feature_dim)
    - self.w: (heads, feature_dim, 1)
    - self.b: (heads, 1, 1)
    """

    out = torch.bmm(input_tensor, self.w) + self.b # (heads, batch, 1)
    out = out.transpose(0, 1).squeeze(2) # (batch, heads)
    labels = torch.ones([batch, heads]) # (batch, heads
    logloss = SOMELOSSFUNC(logits=logits, labels=labels) # output can be a scalar or Tensor of [heads] dimension

    return logloss
```

If the logloss is a scalar, the model optimizes towards one single value. What if the logloss is a tensor of [heads] dimension? Does that mean that I am optimizing w and b for each head independently? Thanks!